# How to convert query for creating a table in Mssql to a query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Hi i had worked on mssql database and wrote a query for creating a table as below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Extb_History](
    [ExtbHistoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SiteID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Count] [int] NULL,
    [ExceptionID] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ExtbHistoryID] ASC) 
WITH 
(
  PAD_INDEX  = OFF
  , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF
  , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
  , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON
  , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

How to write the above query in Mysql Database to create a table,

I tried by changing the data types and syntax but i am getting error near Primary key concept , can anyone please help me in writing the above query in mysql, thatwill be great and helpfull, i am strucked here actually

Comment: Show us what you have tried and we'll try to improve/correct it

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

You'll need something like (*not* tested!):

```
create table extb_history
(
exthistoryb int auto_increment
, siteid int not null
, starttime date not null
, endtime datetime not null
, count int null
, exceptionid int null
, primary key(exthistoryid)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Extb_History
(
    ExtbHistoryID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    SiteID INT NOT NULL,
    StartTime DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    EndTime DATETIME NULL, 
    Count INT NULL,
    ExceptionID INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ExtbHistoryID)
);
```

Comment: Thanks i had done the same, but what about the PAD_INDEX  = OFF
  , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF
  , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF etc conditions here